# unwanted leading blank space on oracle number format

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to pad numbers with leading zeros (total 8 digits) for display. I'm using oracle.

```
select to_char(1011,'00000000') OPE_NO from dual;
select length(to_char(1011,'00000000')) OPE_NO from dual;
```

Instead of '00001011' I get ' 00001011'.
Why do I get an extra leading blank space? What is the correct number formatting string to accomplish this?

P.S. I realise I can just use `trim()`, but I want to understand number formatting better.

@Eddie: I already read the documentation. And yet I still don't understand how to get rid of the leading whitespace.

@David: So does that mean there's no way but to use `trim()`?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6695604/oracle-why-does-the-leading-zero-of-a-number-disappear-when-converting-it-to-c/27946804#27946804 on unwanted leading periods (missing leading zero).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use FM (Fill Mode), e.g.

`select to_char(1011,'FM00000000') OPE_NO from dual;`

Comment: In many cases, *fill mode* is not desirable because it does not right align numbers.

Answer (score 6):

From that same [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00211) mentioned by [EddieAwad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156329/unwanted-leading-blank-space-on-oracle-number-format#156351):

> Negative return values automatically
>   contain a leading negative sign and
>   positive values automatically contain
>   a leading space unless the format
>   model contains the MI, S, or PR format
>   element.

---

**EDIT**: The right way is to use the FM modifier, as answered by Steve Bosman. Read the section about [Format Model Modifiers](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements004.htm#i170559) for more info.