# Why is Oracle's to_char() function adding spaces?

Tags: oracle

Why is Oracle's `to_char()` function adding spaces?

```
select length('012'), 
       length(to_char('012')), 
       length(to_char('12', '000')) 
  from dual;
```

`3, 3, 4`

Comment: Similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156329/unwanted-leading-blank-space-on-oracle-number-format has more detailed answers.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The format mask that you are using is fixed width and allows for a minus sign

Answer (score 131):

The extra leading space is for the potential minus sign.  To remove the space you can use FM in the format:

```
SQL> select to_char(12,'FM000') from dual;

TO_C
----
012
```

By the way, note that to_char takes a NUMBER argument; to_char('012') is implicitly converted to to_char(to_number('012')) = to_char(12)

Comment: just for clarification: `to_char(-12,'FM00')` would result in `-12` and not (as one may fear) `12` or `##`

Answer (score 34):

To make the answers given more clear:

```
select '['||to_char(12, '000')||']', 
       '['||to_char(-12, '000')||']', 
       '['||to_char(12,'FM000')||']' 
from dual


[ 012]                      [-012]                       [012]
```

Answer (score 3):

Be aware when using the 'fm' syntax it will not include any values after the decimal place unless specified using zeros. For example:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(12345, 'fm99,999.00') FROM dual
```

returns: **'12,345.00'**

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(12345, 'fm99,999.99') FROM dual
```

returns: **'12,345.'**

As you can see this would be an issue if you are expecting two zeros after the decimals place (maybe in fee reports for example).