# Oracle - Why does the leading zero of a number disappear when converting it TO_CHAR

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

In Oracle, when converting a number with a leading zero to a character, **why** does the leading number disappear?  Is this logic Oracle specific, or specific to SQL?

Example:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(0.56) FROM DUAL;
/* Result = .56 */
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It's the default formatting that Oracle provides. If you want leading zeros on output, you'll need to explicitly provide the format. Use:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(0.56,'0.99') FROM DUAL;
```

or even:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(.56,'0.99') FROM DUAL;
```

The same is true for trailing zeros:

```
SQL> SELECT TO_CHAR(.56,'0.990') val FROM DUAL;

VAL
------
 0.560
```

The general form of the TO_CHAR conversion function is:

[TO_CHAR](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/TO_CHAR-number.html#GUID-00DA076D-2468-41AB-A3AC-CC78DBA0D9CB)(number, [format](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-24E16D8D-25E4-4BD3-A38D-CE1399F2897C))

Comment: check out http://ss64.com/ora/syntax-numfmt.html for a good list on the different number format available

Comment: The problem with this solution comes when we don't have the exact number of digits after the decimal point. What can we do in this case? A very ugly solution would be to add a `case when myNum < 1 then addLeadingZero end case` and do the same with numbers between -1 and 0. So... what can we do?

Comment: For the sake of my previous comment (more than 3 years ago), I just have to add this: rtrim(to_char('.45', '0.9999999999999'), '0') will return '0.45', which is what we were looking for at the beginning

Comment: This answer is too specific (for one particular case) and should not be the top upvoted. For example, answers by @Vadzim and others cover both the OP's case, and various other for larger numerals.

Comment: @EduCastrillon that's exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 56):

I was looking for a way to format numbers without leading or trailing [spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156329/unwanted-leading-blank-space-on-oracle-number-format), periods, zeros (except one leading zero for numbers less than 1 that should be present).

This is frustrating that such most usual formatting can't be easily achieved in Oracle.

Even [Tom Kyte only suggested long complicated workaround](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2739503983093#65376782952800) like this:

```
case when trunc(x)=x
    then to_char(x, 'FM999999999999999999')
    else to_char(x, 'FM999999999999999.99')
end x
```

But I was able to find shorter solution that mentions the value only once:

```
rtrim(to_char(x, 'FM999999999999990.99'), '.')
```

This [works as expected](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/39743) for all possible values:

```
select 
    to_char(num, 'FM99.99') wrong_leading_period,
    to_char(num, 'FM90.99') wrong_trailing_period,
    rtrim(to_char(num, 'FM90.99'), '.') correct
from (
  select num from (select 0.25 c1, 0.1 c2, 1.2 c3, 13 c4, -70 c5 from dual)
  unpivot (num for dummy in (c1, c2, c3, c4, c5))
) sampledata;

    | WRONG_LEADING_PERIOD | WRONG_TRAILING_PERIOD | CORRECT |
    |----------------------|-----------------------|---------|
    |                  .25 |                  0.25 |    0.25 |
    |                   .1 |                   0.1 |     0.1 |
    |                  1.2 |                   1.2 |     1.2 |
    |                  13. |                   13. |      13 |
    |                 -70. |                  -70. |     -70 |
```

Still looking for even shorter solution.

There is a shortening approarch with custom helper function:

```
create or replace function str(num in number) return varchar2
as
begin
    return rtrim(to_char(num, 'FM999999999999990.99'), '.');
end;
```

But [custom pl/sql functions have significant performace overhead](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:60122715103602) that is not suitable for heavy queries.

Comment: that's helped me a lot. Thx

Comment: To get more decimal places and custom delimiter, I used `RTRIM(TO_CHAR(x, 'FM999999999999990D99999999999999', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '',.'''), ',')`. This is the format used in Czech locale.

Comment: @Palec can you explain the character and the meaning of NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '',.''' ?

Comment: @FrancescoPegoraro, they are decimal and thousands separator, in this order. 1.000,000 would read as a thousand with three decimal places in my country, but as a one with six decimal places in English-speaking countries.
https://datacadamia.com/db/oracle/nls_numeric_characters

Comment: For money this works: `ltrim(to_char('45587.25', '$999,990.99')` or `ltrim(to_char('0', '$999,990.99')`

Answer (score 13):

Seems like the only way to get decimal in a pretty (for me) form requires some ridiculous code.

The only solution I got so far:

```
CASE WHEN xy>0 and xy<1 then '0' || to_char(xy) else to_char(xy)
```

`xy` is a decimal.

```
xy             query result
0.8            0.8  --not sth like .80
10             10  --not sth like 10.00
```

Comment: This is actually the best solution. 

`CASE WHEN xy>0 and xy<1 then '0' || xy else xy||'' end xy`

Answer (score 6):

That only works for numbers less than 1.

```
select to_char(12.34, '0D99') from dual;
-- Result: #####
```

This won't work.

You could do something like this but this results in leading whitespaces:

```
select to_char(12.34, '999990D99') from dual;
-- Result: '     12,34'
```

Ultimately, you could add a TRIM to get rid of the whitespaces again but I wouldn't consider that a proper solution either...

```
select trim(to_char(12.34, '999990D99')) from dual;
-- Result: 12,34
```

Again, this will only work for numbers with 6 digits max.

Edit: I wanted to add this as a comment on DCookie's suggestion but I can't.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to avoid to_char limitations:

```
SELECT 
regexp_replace(regexp_replace(n,'^-\'||s,'-0'||s),'^\'||s,'0'||s)
FROM (SELECT -0.89 n,RTrim(1/2,5) s FROM dual);
```

Comment: using two regex_replace look very suboptimal to me. And original question is rather Why?, not How?

Comment: That's better than to_char, because you are not limited to specific format. You escape ####### situation for big numbers, and you escape undesired zeros after decimal for whole number. It just adds zero for [-1;1] range numbers that looks awkward in native Oracle representation. It's enought just one regexp_replace, if you're sure that the number is positive.

Answer (score 0):

Should work in all cases:

```
SELECT regexp_replace(0.1234, '^(-?)([.,])', '\10\2') FROM dual
```

Answer (score 0):

Below format try if number is like

ex 1 suppose number like 10.1 if apply below format it will be come as 10.10

ex 2 suppose number like  .02 if apply below format it will be come as 0.02

ex 3 suppose number like  0.2 if apply below format it will be come as 0.20

to_char(round(to_number(column_name)/10000000,2),'999999999990D99') as column_name

Answer (score 0):

If your country supports **comma** for decimal, use this:

```
SELECT regexp_replace(
            regexp_replace(to_char(YOUR_NUMBER), '^,', '0,'), -- Positives
            '^-,', '-0,') -- Negatives
```

Otherwise, if your country supports **dots** for decimal, use this:

```
SELECT regexp_replace(
            regexp_replace(to_char(YOUR_NUMBER), '^.', '0.'), -- Positives
            '^-.', '-0.') -- Negatives
```