# No zero before decimal

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to solve this problem. 
This sql

```
select t.currency || ' ' || abs(t.price) 
from apple_month t
where t.price <= 1
```

(t.price is a float)

returns number like this:

```
EUR ,97
USD ,87
```

There are no zero digits before the decimal. What is wrong?

Comment: you could use the `to_char` to format the number returned by abs

Comment: I tried. It doesn't work

Comment: plz share datatypes for all three columns

Comment: t.price is a float,  t.currency is varchar

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove Trailing decimal zero](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18839798/remove-trailing-decimal-zero)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symbol || concatenates strings. In

```
t.currency || ' ' || abs(t.price)
```

you rely hence on the implicit conversion of `abs(t.price)` to string. And this converts the value 0.97 to ',97'.

Use `TO_CHAR` to format your number explicitely. E.g.

```
t.currency || ' ' || to_char(abs(t.price), 'fm9999990d00')
```

Comment: it works but for integer as 0 i want that returns 0 not 0.00

Comment: Okay, I thought you wanted all numbers with two digits after the comma. If not then use 9s. And as there is no format for optional decimal separators you must even trim them: `rtrim(to_char(abs(t.price), 'fm9999990d99'), '.,')`. Or use `CASE` to check whether you have an integer or a decimal number.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add `zero` before decimal if the value is less than 1 then,
try;

```
select t.currency || 
    case when abs(t.price) < 1 then ' 0' || abs(t.price) 
    else ' ' || abs(t.price) end 
from apple_month t
where t.prezzo <= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `TO_CHAR` with a leading zero in the [number format](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34570):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/90381/3)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE APPLE_MONTH( CURRENCY, PRICE, PREZZO ) AS
          SELECT 'EUR',   0.97, 1 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'USD',   0.87, 1 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'USD',   0,    1 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'EUR',  -0.1,  1 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'EUR',  10,    1 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'USD', -12.34, 1 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN TRUNC( price ) = price
            THEN currency || ' ' || TRIM( TO_CHAR( abs(price), '9999990' ) )
            ELSE currency || ' ' || TRIM( TO_CHAR( abs(price), '9999990d00' ) )
            END AS COST
FROM   apple_month
WHERE  prezzo <= 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/90381/3/0)**:

```
|      COST |
|-----------|
|  EUR 0.97 |
|  USD 0.87 |
|     USD 0 |
|  EUR 0.10 |
|    EUR 10 |
| USD 12.34 |
```

Comment: it works but i don't want .oo after 0. When price is 0 i want 0, not 0.00

Comment: @StefanoCarboni Updated