# TO_Char number format model in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, to-char

I don't understand fully how can I use the to_char function to convert a number to a string with the appropriate format model.

The actual number has this type of format:

- Uses comma as decimal separator
- Always 5 decimal numbers
- The integer numbers can up to 6 (potentially can be infinite, but for now they were never more than 6)
- The number can be positive or negative
- The number can begin with a 0

I've tried to use the to_char but I am not able to achieve a result that works with all the conditions

Some examples of how the output should be are
`0,00235` or `156,45623` or `-0,0235` or `-156,45623`

Comment: What have you tried?  What is the data type of the number (precision, scale).  Numbers do not begin with 0.  The string representation of a number may have leading zeros.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle - Why does the leading zero of a number disappear when converting it TO\_CHAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6695604/oracle-why-does-the-leading-zero-of-a-number-disappear-when-converting-it-to-c)

Comment: `TO_CHAR` format models are documented [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-096CA64F-1DA3-4C49-A18B-ECC7518EE56C).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that you are transforming a number into a string. The number does not have any sense of "," or "." or anything--it is a number.

The trick is to get the `TO_CHAR` function to convert the internal number to the string representation that you want.
There are a few problems to worry about: getting the radix point (decimal) correct and dealing with padding.

Here is a working example:

```
SELECT to_char(0.00235,'FM99999999999999990D99999', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '',.''') FROM DUAL;

0,00235

SELECT to_char(156.45823,'FM99999999999999990D99999', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '',.''') FROM DUAL;

156,45823

SELECT to_char(-0.0235,'FM99999999999999990D99999', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '',.''') FROM DUAL;

-0,0235

SELECT to_char(-156.45623,'FM99999999999999990D99999', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '',.''') FROM DUAL;

-156,45623

SELECT to_char(123456789.45623,'FM99999999999999990D99999', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '',.''') FROM DUAL;

123456789,45623
```

The relevant parts of the mask:

`FM`is used to trim leading and trailing blanks that Oracle normally uses to pad out numbers.

`D` is the radix point, depending on your NLS settings.

`NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS ...` is an override of your local NLS settings--this might not be necessary if your locale uses a comma for the decimal, but it is a way you can force this behavior in a database with, say, North American settings.

Answer (score 1):

Shamelessly stolen from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27946804/7948962) from @Vadzim.

You should be able to get the format you're looking for by using this pattern:

```
rtrim(to_char(num, 'FM999999999999990.99'), '.')
```

https://rextester.com/QRSD48676

```
SELECT rtrim(to_char('0,00235', 'FM999999999999990.99999'), '.') FROM DUAL\\
SELECT rtrim(to_char('156,45623', 'FM999999999999990.99999'), '.') FROM DUAL\\  
SELECT rtrim(to_char('-0,0235', 'FM999999999999990.99999'), '.') FROM DUAL\\
SELECT rtrim(to_char('-156,45623', 'FM999999999999990.99999'), '.') FROM DUAL\\
```

Results:

```
0.00235
156.45623
-0.0235
-156.45623
```