# Create separators in sql query

Tags: sql-server

Is there an option to create separators in sql query?

```
EXECUTE ('
Select 
A 
from dbo.Table') AT BAZ_PROD
```

```
   A    |
---------
92759.4 |
```

I want to see: 92 759.4  instead of 92759.4

i tried

```
EXECUTE ('
Select 
FORMAT(A, ''###,###,###.##'') AS A
from dbo.Table') AT BAZ_PROD
```

and have error:

> The OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for the linked server "BAZ_PROD" returned the message "ORA-00904:" FORMAT ": invalid ID".

Comment: This sort of thing should be done in your presentation layer.  So if you are exporting to excel or showing it in tableau you would format it there.

Comment: Your error is Oracle? But you have tagged SQL Server... please ensure your tags are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use TO_CHAR function,  you can find some good example in https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_char.php

for formatted numbers also you can look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57063906/to-char-number-format-model-in-oracle) answer.

Answer (score 1):

in SQL Server you must use the FORMAT function to do so.

```
SELECT FORMAT(92759.4, '00 000.00')
```

The remaining probleme will be the leading 0

But, because this is a cosmectic question, you must not do that at the RDBMS level, but, instaed, at the application level.